# Need suggestions with reading text files by every n-th line in Raku

Tags: raku

I am looking for some suggestions on how I can read text files by every n-th file in Raku/perl6.

In bioinformatics research, sometimes we need to parse text files in a somewhat less than straightforward manner. Such as Fastq files, which store data in groups of 4 lines at a time. Even more, these Fastq files come in pairs. So if we need to parse such files, we may need to do something like reading 4 lines from the first Fastq file, and reading 4 lines from the second Fastq file, then read the next 4 lines from the first Fastq file, and then read the next 4 lines from the second fastq file, ......

May I have some suggestions regarding what is the best way to approach this problem? Raku's "IO.lines" approach seems to be able to handle each line one at a time. but not sure how to handle every n-th line

An example fastq file pair: https://github.com/wtwt5237/perl6-for-bioinformatics/tree/master/Come%20on%2C%20sister/fastq
What we tried before with "IO.lines": https://github.com/wtwt5237/perl6-for-bioinformatics/blob/master/Come%20on%2C%20sister/script/benchmark2.p6

Comment: *May I have suggestions* is not a specific question. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so and run into a snag, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Take a look at the `.batch` method.

Answer (score 8):

Reading 4 lines at a time from 2 files and processing them into a single thing, can be easily done with `zip` and `batch`:

```
my @filenames = <file1 file2>;
for zip @filenames.map: *.IO.lines.batch(4) {
    # expect ((a,b,c,d),(e,f,g,h))
}
```

This will keep producing until at least one of the files is fully handled.  An alternate for `batch` is `rotor`: this will keep going while both files fill up 4 lines completely.  Other ways of finishing the loop are with also specifying the `:partial` flag with `rotor`, and using `roundrobin` instead of `zip`.  YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `lines` method. Raku `Sequence`s are lazy. This means that iterating over an expression like `"somefile".IO.lines` will only ever read one line into memory, never the whole file. In order to do the latter you would need to assign the `Sequence` to an `Array`.

The `pairs` method helps you getting the index of the lines. In combination with the *divisible by* operator `%%` we can write

```
"somefile".IO.lines.pairs.grep({ .key && .key %% 4 }).map({ .value })
```

in order to get a sequence of every 4th line in a file.

Comment: You can do this more consisely without the pairs like `"somefile".IO.lines.grep({ $++ && ++$ %% 4 })`